# cakephp $this->User->save($this->data) error on edit function of a logged user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create the "edit" profile page for a logged user in cakephp. This would be the function to add/edit information about the user.
I get an error during the $this->User->save($this->data) function and I don't understand what is the problem.

```
public function edit() {
   $this->User->id = $this->Auth->User('id');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'), 'flash_success');
           // $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            var_dump($this->invalidFields());

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash_failure');
        }
    } else {
        //autocompleto il form
        $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->User('id'));
    }
}
```

The view is:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=> 'Name'));
echo $this->Form->input('surname', array('label'=> 'Surname'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=> 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); 
?>
```

Comment: `I get an error` - error messages are always helpful. "an error" is less so.

Comment: sorry there isn't a visual error, doesn't do the save of the User model, so the if /else goes to else

Comment: Can you show the code for the `save()` method so we can see where/why it would return something that evaluates to `FALSE`? Also showing `var_dump($this->User->save($this->data))` would probably be helpful.

Comment: I guess there might be problem with the `echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=> 'hidden'));` - there is probably no value

Comment: var_dump($this->User->save($this->data)) returns "bool(false)", the code for the save method is the standard code of the cakephp framework

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="data[User][id]" value="2" id="UserId"/> have a value and is the right for the logged in user

Comment: Are invalidFields empty? Are there any behaviors? beforeSave/beforeValidate callbacks?

Comment: there is only a function  public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'confirm','logout');
    }

Comment: It seems that everything is correct with your code. Try to print $this->request->data before saving and use die; to check is there something wrong with the form array.

Comment: $this->request->data prints correctly the data of the form. It's possible that i can't save User data because there are some Auth restrictions? in the beforefilter() of the users controller i've         parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add', 'confirm','logout');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you use `Auth` component. If your `Auth::authorize` default value is overridden ensure that you give user proper rights to perform data writing (maybe he only allowed to read).

Another issue could be your `$validate` declaration in model, where you force user to enter field value (using `'required' = true`) but actually this field is not even displayed on View. You could avoid this validation rule on data edit if `'on' => 'create'` is defined inside.

Also I would recommend use CakePHP [debug()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html) instead of var_dump() for debugging purpose.